# why does 좋아하다 pronounce as 조아하다?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

I am a beginner, and with my current knowledge, when there is ㅇ after the previous final consonant, the previous final consonant combines with the vowel after ㅇ to pronounce.
So, 좋아하다 is supposed to pronounce as 조하하다, but it does not.
Is there any sound change rule I don't know?

Answer (score 4):

## *ㅎ 탈락 (H-dropping)*

> ## [Standard Korean §2.4.12.4](http://www.tufs.ac.jp/ts/personal/choes/korean/nanboku/Barum.html)
>
> **‘ㅎ(ㄶ, ㅀ)’ 뒤에 모음으로 시작된 어미나 접미사가 결합되는 경우에는, ‘ㅎ’을 발음하지 않는다.**
>
> ***A “ㅎ” (or that in “ㄶ,” “ㅀ”) followed by a conjugation/suffix that doesn’t have an initial consonant, is silent.***
>
> - 낳은[나은]
> - 놓아[노아]
> - 쌓이다[싸이다]
> - 많아[마ː나]
> - 않은[아는]
> - 닳아[다라]
> - 싫어도[시러도]

- The word: “좋아하다.”
- Its morphemes: “좋-,” “**-아**,” “하-,” “-다.”
- Since the conjugation “-아” has no initial consonant, the “ㅎ” followed by it is silent.
- The pronunciation: “조아하다” (not “조하하다”).

---

**Basically**: if you see a “ㅎ”-ending stem followed by an “ㅇ,” skip the “ㅎ” when you pronounce it.